# Need to find the minimum value of a 4x2 array while ignoring the diagonal

Tags: c++, arrays, minimum

I need to find the lowest value in an array that isn't in the main diagonal, I have written some code but it seems to pick either the second or the last value only (depending on which one is the lowest).

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[4][2];
    int Min,i,j;
    cout<<"Type 8 numbers";
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
            Min=arr[0][1];
            if(i!=j and Min > arr[i][j])
            {
                Min=arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"The values of the array are: \n";
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
    }
    cout<<"The lowest value is: "<<Min;
}
```

If I type 1-8 the returned value is 2, if I type 8-1 the returned Value is 1, in both of these cases the code is working as I intended, but if I type something like 8,6,4,1,2,3,4,5, the lowest value is returned as 5, I'm very new to coding and would appreciate any help.

Comment: `Min=arr[0][1];` should be done only once...

Comment: A four-by-two array doesn't have a "main diagonal", so it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
Min=arr[0][1];
```

is bad because

- It reads uninitialized `arr[0][1]` when `i = 0, j = 0`.
- It writes `arr[0][1]` to `Min` unconditionally, even if current `Min` is smaller than that.

Instead of this:

```
Min=arr[0][1];
if(i!=j and Min > arr[i][j])
{
    Min=arr[i][j];
}
```

This will work, for example:

```
if(i!=j and ((i==0 and j==1) or Min > arr[i][j]))
{
    Min=arr[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Min=arr[0][1]` line is inside both loops, which means each time when you are trying to compare Min and the current element `arr[i][j]`, you just threw away whatever smallest value stored in `Min` and replaced it with `arr[0][1]`.

Hence the code as you have written returns either the last number or `arr[0][1]`, whichever is smaller.

You should really only initialise this `Min` once before your loops begin. i.e.

```
Min = arr[0][1]
for(i = 0; i < 4;i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
     // Compare Min and arr[i][j] and reassign the smaller one to Min if i != j
    }
}
```